# Use multiple conditions in SQL WHERE clause using OR

Tags: php, sql, select, where-clause

I've got the following SQL statement in my PHP code:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM coaches WHERE pastors='1' OR all_categories='1' ORDER BY l_name";
```

but the WHERE portion after the OR is ignored.  Is my code correct?  Is there a better way to code it?

Comment: It's not ignored - it will cause any records that do not have pastors = 1 but do have all_categories = 1 to be included in your result set.   What are you trying to accomplish?  This query is otherwise fine.

Comment: I am trying to get it to select database entries if there is a 1 in a particular category, in this case "pastors", or if there is a 1 in the "all_categories" category.  Basically there are some people that are not particular and want to be listed everywhere.  At this point I wonder if it's better to just put 1's in all of the categories for those people.

Comment: For two simple conditionals, parentheses are unnecessary.

Comment: Do not hack it and put in "1" for all categories - your data should always be represented as accurately as possible or you will regret it later.   Why do you feel this code isn't working?  This WILL properly select both record groups if that's what your records have in the fields.  I think you have an error elsewhere (either the records don't have exactly '1' in the column, etc).

Comment: As others have said, there is nothing wrong with your query. The `OR` is not being ignored. Your problem is sure to be _something else_ entirely. And that _something else_ is unfortunately something you have not included in your question. So you won't get any helpful answers as a result.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions.  Even though people said it should work, for some reason it wasn't.  The easiest solution was to simply set every true/false to 1 for those individuals who want to be in all categories instead of trying to fight against the OR which looks correct but won't work.

Answer (score -1):

> I am trying to get it to select database entries if there is a 1 in a particular category, in this case "pastors", or if there is a 1 in the "all_categories" category.

From the looks of it, your code does just that.

You're just forgetting ASC or DESC at the end of it.

It should look more like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM coaches WHERE pastors='1' OR all_categories='1' ORDER BY l_name ASC";
```

Comment: Why do you feel parentheses are necessary?

Comment: Parens are not necessary in this case.

Comment: Unless there are other criteria within the where statement (such as an `AND`) the parentheses are completely unnecessary  (note that they can be useful in other situations).

Comment: You don't 'need' ASC or DESC at the end necessarily. If ommited MySQL assumes ASC. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html